# Jquery binds the click events sequentially after every .load()

Tags: events, jquery

I am loading a .php file into a div tag using .load() function of jquery :

```
$('#content').load('MY_URL');
```

I have bound several events using .live and all of them work fine after loading the MY_URL.
but the problem is : when I load the second page into the latter loaded page (suppose #content) the events are fired twice :
for example I have bound a click event to show and hide a div tag but after loading the second page it fires two times and shows and hide the div tag sequentially that you can say it doesn't work at all.

I have read all problems like this and I can say all their problems have been solved using .live instead of .bind but mine did not get solved ! please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unbind your first live event before firing 2nd live event

> $('#content').die("click");

Comment: I think that you did not understand my problem. I am not binding a click event to $('#content')
the problem is after loading the second page